# Eclipse/STS Java 8 Migration Support?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

After watching "[Smart Migration to JDK 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8HsVgUDCn8)", I try to figure out how the latest version of STS 3.6.3.SR1 supports the migration. I can't see what it is supported to do as described in "[Eclipse Luna: Ready for JavaTM 8](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/june/article1.php)". For example, "convert to Lambda express" doesn't show up while "extract to local variable" does after invoking Quick Assists (Ctrl+1). STS is built on top of Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1).

What is missing here?

The following screen shot is the configuration:
[image]

And the following screen shot is about what the Quick Assists brings up.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

STS 3.6.3.SR1 is indeed based on Eclipse 4.4 and includes the Java8 support. I tried this and I can access all the various Java8 support features from within Java8 projects in STS. I guess that you can select the Java8 compiler level when creating a project, correct? I've seen the Ctrl-1 showing the "convert to lambda" option not showing up in all the various places, but in very specific ones instead. For me it shows up at the method of an anonymous inner class (for example), but not in the "new ..." statement.

Maybe posting a screenshot of the source -> cleanup tab might help to figure out that is wrong here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The project was set up before Java 8 coming out. I change the Java compiler level to 8. I have only tried the conversion on looping. I guess that is one of places Eclipse can make the conversion.

Comment: After running the clean up, I don't see any related information.

Comment: what happens if you run pure Eclipse 4.4.2?

Comment: After installing the Eclipse 4.4.2, I test the sample code and the result is the same. So, Eclipse Luna doesn't support the looping Java 8 migration.

Comment: I would suggest to open a bug report at Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT to introduce this Java8 specific refactoring for those loops.

Comment: A ticket covering a bigger scope on this subject https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431967 It is good to know for a future reference.